# Is there a way to run a Kibana Query and display results in Jenkins after a build?

Tags: jenkins, kibana

I would like to run a build, have a plugin or something communicate with Kibana and return query results to jenkins in some fashion... has anyone done this? ideas? suggestions? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI if anyone is looking into this in the future, you can query Elasticsearch directly from Jenkins :)

Comment: Good to hear that, thanks for sharing. Please post some example Url / configuration screenshot(so people will have some leads to follow) and accept the answer so people will see it needs no more answers